# Please explain why this C code gives me a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm a beginner trying to learn C. The following code gives me a segmentation fault when I run it. Can anyone explain why, or show me my error?

```
struct frac sum(struct frac f1, struct frac f2);
struct frac {
int *numer;
int *denom;
};
struct frac sum(struct frac f1, struct frac f2) {
struct frac rv;
*rv.numer = (*f1.numer)*(*f2.denom) + (*f2.numer)*(*f1.denom);
*rv.denom = (*f1.denom)*(*f2.denom);
return rv;
}
int main() {
int n = 5;
int d = 10;
struct frac myFrac1 = {&n, &d};
struct frac myFrac2 = {&n, &d};
struct frac myFrac3 = sum(myFrac1, myFrac2);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using pointers here? `rv.numer` and `rv.denom` aren't initialized to anything so dereferencing them is undefined behavior.

Comment: OK, I removed the * from rv.numer and rv.denom, but now I get  **warning: assignment to 'int *' from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast.**  If I try to cast the right side of the expression to a pointer like `rv.denom =(int *) ((*f1.denom)*(*f2.denom));` I get  **warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size.**

Comment: Because you're using pointers. You either need to point `rv.numer` and `rv.demon` at something (e.g. the result of a `malloc` call or the pointer to an existing int like you did in `main` with the other two objects), or make `numer` and `denom` ints rather than pointers.

Comment: So I first need to allocate memory to `rv.numer` and `rv.denom` before I can have them point to the result of some arithmetic on pointers?

Comment: Please do not edit your original post in such a way as to change the content that represents the very essence of what your question is about.  Edits should be limited to formatting, and/or _adding_ new information to clarify questions in comments.  Changing the code leads to confusing new viewers, and causes content already offered  via comments and answers to be misunderstood.  I have rolled the post back to its original for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

*"...code gives me a segmentation fault when I run it. Can anyone explain why, or show me my error"*

First, there are a few things that would show-up if compiling in debug mode that would likely prevent you ever getting a seg-fault if you were able to see them, and respond by addressing each one:

When I ***compile*** with normal warnings on:

[image]

Not Initializing variables is one of the most commonly ignored, but costly mistakes programmers (new and old) make.  Always initialize.

Why the seg fault - In your original code, I see this when I ***run***:

[image]
[image]

Attempting to de-reference an uninitialized pointer will almost always result in a segmentation fault.

Just a few suggestions that will address the errors above:
For readability throughout the example adaptation of your code uses a `typedef` to create `frac_s`.  Using pointers in the way your original post does would require dynamic memory allocation in places would be just as well served by non-pointers, i.e. the `struct` members.  So, *note the use of non-pointer members* instead.  Pointer usage below is limited to function arguments, and the return type of `sum(,,)`, thus simplifying the code considerably, but requiring dynamic memory allocation and `free()`.  Compare the following to your code to see the extent of changes...

```
typedef struct  {
    int numer;
    int denom;
}frac_s;


frac_s * sum(frac_s *f1, frac_s *f2);

frac_s * sum(frac_s *f1, frac_s *f2) {
    frac_s * rv = calloc(1, sizeof(*rv)) ;
    if(rv)
    {
        rv->numer = (f1->numer)*(f2->denom) + (f2->numer)*(f1->denom);
        rv->denom = (f1->denom)*(f2->denom);
    }
    return rv;
}

int main(void) {
    int n = 5;
    int d = 10;

    frac_s myFrac1 = {n, d};
    frac_s myFrac2 = {n, d};
    frac_s *myFrac3 = sum(&myFrac1, &myFrac2);
    if(myFrac3)
    {
        //use myFracs;
        free(myFracs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

program will crash on the second line

```
struct frac rv;
*rv.numer = (*f1.numer)*(*f2.denom) + (*f2.numer)*(*f1.denom);
```

because, you define rv in the stack. rv.number could be anything.

in most cases, *(rv.numer)is a place you can not write.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
struct frac sum(struct frac f1, struct frac f2);

struct frac {
    int *numer;
    int *denom;
};

struct frac sum(struct frac f1, struct frac f2) {
    struct frac rv;
    rv.numer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    rv.denom = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *rv.numer = (*f1.numer)*(*f2.denom) + (*f2.numer)*(*f1.denom);
    *rv.denom = (*f1.denom)*(*f2.denom);
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    int n = 5;
    int d = 10;

    struct frac myFrac1 = {&n, &d};
    struct frac myFrac2 = {&n, &d};
    struct frac myFrac3 = sum(myFrac1, myFrac2);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

The result is that both `rv.numer` and `rv.denom` point to 100 at the end.

Comment: These added parentheses don't change anything. `*rv.numer` and `*(rv.numer)` are equivalent.

Comment: I don't think so, ```*rv.numer``` will do *rv first and then try to get the numer element. However, ```*(rv.numer)``` will find the numer element first and then do * on it.

Comment: No. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. `.` (Structure and union member access) has higher precedence than `*` (Indirection (dereference)). The page even gives an example of how `*p++` is equivalent to `*(p++)` and the postfix increment operator has the same precedence as `.`

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do with your edit. This is a C question, not C++

Comment: You have pointers as your struct members. They need to be allocated memory before they can store anything. Another option is to point them to already allocated memory like you did in ```struct frac myFrac1 = {&n, &d};```

Comment: You can vote up the answer if you found it correct.

Comment: After copying this code and `#include <stdlib.h>` my program runs without errors, but I now have a new issue. My logic should have `rv.numer` point to `50` and `rv.denom` point to `100` but `rv.numer` and `rv.denom` now both point to `4`.

Comment: Why? ```5*10+5*10 = 100``` and ```10*10=100```

Comment: That was a typo, they should both point to `100`, but point to `4`.  Also, it seems like your screenshot is of code in C++. I am trying to do this in C and do not know C++.

Comment: C++ can run C code. C++ has been designed to be compatible with C. Also I might delete my answer since it is reducing my reputation here.

Comment: ```rv.denom``` for example points to 100 but is equal to its memory address. I feel you have a problem in this.